# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Prerequisite Upgrade fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-installer, prerequisites

We have a Visual Studio Installer which has many prerequisites one which is SQL Server Express 2008 R2 (English version)

We have a target computer which has SQL Server Express 2005 in Italian.

The installation fails with the error message as in this screenshot:

[image]

Is there a way to change the command line arguments to support a language independent upgrade?

UPDATE:
"Localized versions of SQL Server can only be upgraded to localized versions of the same language, and cannot be upgraded to the English-language version."
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210665(v=sql.105).aspx

Does this mean the only way would be to backup data, uninstall 2005 and install the 2008 English version?

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem by creating a named instance of the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database.